# Android RecyclerView item OnClickListener without inner classes

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement list item click listener on Android RecyclerView. Most solutions i've found add anonymous inner class listener to view in `onBindViewHolder` method. So, we will constantly have new objects created while scrolling our list. Some solutions I've found avoid this by adding `ViewHolder` as a tag to item view in `onCreateViewHolder`. This allows to get current position using `getAdapterPosition()`, but how can we get data at current positions without a reference on it in the activity or fragment? I use `Loader` to load data and put it to the adapter, so I don'want to keep a reference to data in `Fragment`.

I save a reference to current data item in a `ViewHolder` object in `onBindViewHolder`.

Is this solution correct and acceptable?

Thanks a lot.

Code example below

```
    private static class JobTypesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JobTypesAdapter.JobTypesViewHolder> {
    private @NonNull List<JobType> jobTypes;
    private @Nullable View.OnClickListener onItemClickListener;

    JobTypesAdapter(@NonNull List<JobType> jobTypes, @Nullable View.OnClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.jobTypes = jobTypes;
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    void setData(@NonNull List<JobType> jobTypes) {
        this.jobTypes = jobTypes;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public @NonNull JobTypesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_job_types, viewGroup, false);
        JobTypesViewHolder holder = new JobTypesViewHolder(tv);

        if (onItemClickListener != null) {
            tv.setTag(holder);
            tv.setOnClickListener(onItemClickListener);
        }
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull JobTypesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        JobType jobType = jobTypes.get(position);
        holder.setJobType(jobType);
        holder.txtJobTypeName.setText(jobType.getName());
    }

    @Override public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull JobTypesViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        holder.setJobType(null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jobTypes.size();
    }

    static class JobTypesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtJobTypeName;
        private @Nullable JobType jobType;

        JobTypesViewHolder(TextView itemTextView) {
            super(itemTextView);
            txtJobTypeName = itemTextView;
        }

        @Nullable JobType getJobType() {
            return jobType;
        }

        void setJobType(@Nullable JobType jobType) {
            this.jobType = jobType;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my onClickListener code:

```
        jobTypesAdapter = new JobTypesAdapter(
            Collections.<JobType>emptyList(),
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    JobTypesAdapter.JobTypesViewHolder holder = (JobTypesAdapter.JobTypesViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    JobType jobType = holder.getJobType();
                    if (jobType != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, jobType.getId() + "; " + jobType.getName());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the click listener in the holder class:

...extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder **implements View.OnClickListener**

And assign the listener in the constructor. So, as next:

```
static class JobTypesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView txtJobTypeName;
    @Nullable 
    private JobType jobType;

    JobTypesViewHolder(TextView itemTextView) {
        super(itemTextView);
        txtJobTypeName = itemTextView;

        // Set click listener
        itemTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      ...
      ...
    }

    @Nullable 
    JobType getJobType() {
        return jobType;
    }

    void setJobType(@Nullable JobType jobType) {
        this.jobType = jobType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your answer! So I can get rid of setting ViewHolder as a tag of the View, but I still must keep a reference to data (JobType) in my ViewHolder, and refresh it in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: The ViewHolder is a helper class to put any functionality that a View for a RecyclerView may need. Is fine to add such information if the View requires it.